# VisualSVN commit binary files "connection forcibly closed"

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server

I have installed VisualSVN latest version on Windows 7 and I'm using TortoiseSVN as client.

Server is over internet and bandwidth is 100KBps.

Everything is OK; I can commit and update to it. The only problem I have is that I cannot commit big binary files like .png and .jar. By a big file, I mean more than 50KB. I can commit icons, but I cannot commit normal images.

TortoiseSVN adds .png files as `mimetype:application/octet-stream`.

[EDIT]
Various errors in server log:

```
Unable to PUT new contents for /svn/MediaStore_App/!svn/txr/12-t/MainActivity/libs/android-support-v44.jar.  [403, #0]
[client 151.240.214.18]
```

...

```
Could not prepare to write the file  [500, #160044]
[client 151.240.214.18]
```

...

```
Could not get next bucket brigade  [500, #0]
[client 151.240.214.18]
```

I have also tested with 1.5MB text files and there is no problem.
What should I do? Should I change any config in SVN Server?

Comment: Specify exact error wording on client and what's logged to VisualSVN Server's eventlog.

Comment: On client error is "Connection is actively refused by server" something like this. and there was no details, and on server i think VisualSVN has installed it's own server (a variation of apache http module) and i don't know exactly where it is logging

Comment: See http://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00028/ on how to check server logs.

Comment: thanks a lot, I'm trying to comit a jar and a png file, but errors are different as you can see, i have edited my post and added error messages

Comment: make sure that TortoiseSVN client is up-to-date and check your antivirus and proxy (if any exists). I suggest disabling the antivirus and see whether it changes the behavior. BTW are you able to commit these files from another workstation?

Comment: We have downloaded VisualSVN and tortoise yesterday, and as i know there is no firewall or antivirus (i can commit other files and update from repository) The only exceptions are these two files, tomorrow i will check from another workstation to see whether it will be fixed or not

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strange error 500 with svn commit on one simple file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8857747/strange-error-500-with-svn-commit-on-one-simple-file)

Comment: The "duplicate" that I pointed to with the close vote was the first hit on Google with your last error message (a little research goes a long way!). Also, try disabling your antivirus, some AV behaviors are known to cause trouble with Subversion and sometimes throw false positives. Or, you might just need to restart Apache on the server.

Comment: I've already read that post, his problem is similar, but not exactly the same, because i had different types of errors.
And on that post they have said a few solutions that as they said, they are not working on all scenarios and are just some random tries that may work.
I have disabled everything and restarted whole operating system, but did not work.
if any progress happens, I'll update my post so i may be useful for others